# Ad Hoc app's loading time (launch time) is much longer than App Store signed app on iPad?

Tags: ios, ipad, time, loading, launch

My iPad is on iOS v8.2, X-code is on Version 6.3 (6D570), SDK 8.3.

One of my app is available on App Store. Recently I find that for the same build of this app, if I signed it myself with an ad hoc certificat, its first loading time is significantly longer than the one that is downloaded from app store.

By **loading time**, I mean the time after I tap on the icon of the app, it is darkened, until I can see the launch screen.

For the app store version, when I tap on the app icon, I can see the launch screen instantly. The lagging is no more than 1s.

However, for the ad hoc version, after the icon being tapped, I need to wait for 3 to 4 seconds until I can see the launch screen.

And even I create an empty project either in Objective-C or Swift, I don't change any of the code, if I signed it with ad hoc certificate and get it installed on my iPad, it takes some seconds to launch.

Have I did something wrong ?
How can I improve the loading performance of my app ?

Thank you in advance for your advice.

Jianbin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that this problem is caused by the large number of provisioning profiles installed on the device. When I removed all of those provisioning profiles from my devices, the problem is solved.

Please refer to this question and the accepted answer
[Enterprise (in-house) Swift application quits on launch on iOS9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32747961/enterprise-in-house-swift-application-quits-on-launch-on-ios9/33045154#33045154)

Answer (score 0):

This is because of 2 reasons:

1. You are debugging the app. That means the app sends every method call to your computer so you can see what happens.
2. You run the app in "Debug" config, which does not use optimizations 
   (-O0 vs -Ofast).

Comment: 1. I didn't connect my app to the debugger. I exported the app as ipa and installed to to my iPad through iTunes.
2. I did use the optimizations, but they don't help.

Comment: @Jibeex oh so the only difference is the  certificate?

Comment: that is why I find strange.